# Sqlite3 database is not connected in iPhone 4 running iOS 5.0.1, on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks

Tags: iphone, ios, database, sqlite

Sqlite3 database is not connected in iPhone 4 running iOS 5.0.1, on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks. My apps 4 times rejected in Itunes Apple store due to this reason.
I am using XCode 3.2.4 using iPhone 3.2 iOS 4.1. where this app running well.

I write this codes-

```
/// @ AppDelegate.m file 

-(void)createDatabaseIfNeeded {

BOOL success;
NSError *error;

//FileManager - Object allows easy access to the File System.
NSFileManager *FileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

//Get the complete users document directory path.
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

//Get the first path in the array.
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


//Create the complete path to the database file.
NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"passmanager.sqlite"];

//Check if the file exists or not.
success = [FileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

//If the database is present then quit.
if(success) return;

//the database does not exists, so we will copy it to the users document directory]
NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"passmanager.sqlite"];

//Copy the database file to the users document directory.
success = [FileManager copyItemAtPath:dbPath toPath:databasePath error:&error];

//If the above operation is not a success then display a message.
//Error message can be seen in the debugger's console window.
if(!success)
    NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to copy the database. Error: %@.", [error localizedDescription]);
}


-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application{

// createDatabaseIfNeeded method for first time to create database in new iPhone
[self createDatabaseIfNeeded];
[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

And Error gives accroding to Apple in the code in Some ViewController page

```
// @ viewController.m

sqlite3 *database;

int result = sqlite3_open("passmanager.sqlite", &database);

if(result != SQLITE_OK){
sqlite3_close(database);
UIAlertView *alert = 
[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Database Connected" 
                       message:@"No" 
                      delegate:self 
                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                     otherButtonTitles:nil]; 

[alert show];     
[alert release];            
}
else{ 
  // some stuff
}
```

Every time Apple complained that if Condition is true as "Database Connected No"
While In my system else part is executing. 
Please help me. Thax in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the path of the database you are trying to open is incomplete, it should be

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"passmanager.sqlite"];

int result = sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database);
```

as that is what you set in `createDatabaseIfNeeded`

Comment: yes this code works when I changed path in viewController.m file as full path for database. Thanking you my apps has been approved. see at iTunes ManagePassword.